# Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host remoto

Tags: android, android-studio

Então galera, venho quebrando a cabeça com esse problema no Android Studio:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1 - Eu já dei restart no adb: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029809/android-studio-java-io-ioexception-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed

2 - Já atualizei o drive do dispositivo e desabilitei o modo de debug do android e modo de desenvolvedor (e reativei novamente): 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050538/android-studio-fail-to-install-app-on-device

3 - Já comprei outro cabo USB;

E até agora nada!

Para isso eu estou usando: 
- Android Studio 3.1.4; 
- Samsung SM-J320M;

Obs: quando eu tento rodar o app e esse erro acontece, na janela de Seleção do Dispositivo de Deploy (***Select Deployment Target***), aparece que o dispositivo está OFFLINE, mas em nenhum momento é percebido que ele foi desconectado do USB.
Como eu posso resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depois de muitas pesquisas, eu finalmente resolvi meu problema com base em uma resposta do fórum da Unity.

Isso acontece devido a instabilidade do aparelho em relação à conexão USB. Então, nesse caso, o melhor a se fazer é conectar o ADB ao aparelho via wifi. Para tal:

1 - Abra o `cmd` fazendo tecla `Win + R`, digitando cmd e dando `Enter`
2 - Reinicie na porta 555 com o seguinte comando
- `adb tcpip 5555` 
3 - Com endereço IP do seu dispositivo em mãos digite `adb connect ip.do.seu.dispositivo` (seu smartphone deve estar na mesma rede local)

Seu tudo correr como esperado, será exibida uma mensagem informando que o ADB está conectado ao aparelho (IP). Pronto! Agora ele está disponível na lista de devices. Dê um `adb devices` ou vá até o *Android Studio* e seu dispositivo estará listado.

Link para a resposta original: http://answers.unity.com/answers/1354067/view.html